# How to get firebase snapshot of matching children?

Tags: javascript, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase data structure in this format
[image]

when a user enter 5133-01-329-5971 in a search field I want to be able to get the snapshot of

5133-01-329-5971-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1508951718305

5133-01-329-5971-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1508966816945

because they contain a match of the user input.

this code will give me all the children in the node

```
  var itemdetailref = Cataloguedatabase.ref('/Listings/');

  return itemdetailref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){

  })
```

How can I get the snapshot of all the children that matches 5133-01-329-5971?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have one special child you are looking for, you can enter this string in the ref var. Something like this:

```
let uid = "5133-01-329-5971";
let child = "-OkqcPp3xJwfgmNinwGsKZmAa8xt1-1508966816945";
var itemdetailref = Cataloguedatabase.ref('/Listings/'+uid+child);

return itemdetailref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){

})
```

But if you search multiple childs like you do in your example you have to get every child and then just take these which include your userid. Something like:

```
var itemdetailref = Cataloguedatabase.ref('/Listings/'+uid+child);

return itemdetailref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
            let key = childSnapshot.key;
            let uid = "5133-01-329-5971";
            //use ES6 includes function
            if(key.includes(uid)){
                myFunction(childSnapshot.val());
            }
        });
})
```